# APNSWrapper push notification fails to other devices if one device token is invalid

Tags: python, ios, push-notification

We are using the following code to deliver APNS notifications

```
iHPush:
def __init__(self):
    self.wrapper = APNSWrapper.APNSNotificationWrapper('/path/to/my/production.pem', False)

def push(self, token='', alertmessage='', ubadge=0):
    deviceToken = binascii.unhexlify(token)
    message = APNSWrapper.APNSNotification()
    message.token(deviceToken)
    message.badge(1)
    message.alert(alertmessage)
    message.sound()
    self.wrapper.append(message)

def notify(self):
    self.wrapper.notify()

pushObj = iHPush()
#this token is used for sandbox test
pushObj.push("b9236...x0", "haha", 0)
#this one is production token
pushObj.push("b9236...40", "haha", 0)
pushObj.notify()
```

Combining the sandbox and production tokens in the one notification message result in no notifications being delivered. If we add the second one twice, messages are sent successfully.

I understand that if the token is valid or not should be handled by the APNS. Why can't we send message this way?

Comment: I can't help with why, but I can ask why you would design an app like this?  You should know whether you are testing or not - so you should know whether to talk to the sandbox or production gateway and which device id to use

Comment: Thanks to Paulw11. I'm worried about if one production token is invalid, for example, user has uninstalled our apps, does it will affect the following ones

Comment: Ok.  That makes sense.  You need to subscribe to the feedback service to receive notification on failed delivery so that you can remove the device from your database, but I agree you are correct - a failed delivery is a possibility and something that should be handled on the Apple side. It may be worth looking into some debugging on the python library side - there is a feedback error code from Apple if something goes wrong, but "invalid token" isn't one of them.